# Fix if condition in shell script

Tags: bash

I have these if conditions, but it has compile errors. How can I fix it?

```
if [ $DEVICE_ID == "" ]; then
```

I get error:

```
line 63: [: ==: unary operator expected


if [ 'ls -l Mytest*.log | wc -l' -eq 1 ]; then
```

i get error:

```
line 68: [: ls -l Kernel*.log | wc -l: integer expression expected
```

Comment: Brackets are from shell and doesn't support empty variables.
You should use Bash with double brackets or add double quotes around $DEVICE_ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the variable:

```
if [ "$DEVICE_ID" == "" ]; then
```

But it would be better to do:

```
if [ -z "$DEVICE_ID" ];
```

The second error is that you need to use backquotes:

```
if [ $(ls -l Mytest*.log | wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a better way to find if there are files with name 'MyTest*.log'?

Comment: Terrible `bash` practise spotted!

Comment: @michael  Yes, there are much better ways, and checking that `ls -l Mytest*.log` produces one line of output does not even do that.  If you want to see if a file exists that matches the name `MyTest*.log`, a simple check is `if test MyTest*.log != "MyTest*.log"`

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash, use double brackets for conditional expressions: they are smarter about unquoted variables

```
if [[ $DEVICE_ID = "" ]]; then ...
```

would work (note: `=` instead of `==` for plain string equality instead of pattern matching)

For presence of files use an array

```
shopt -s nullglob
files=( *.log )
if (( ${#files[@]} > 0 )); the. Echo "there are log files"; fi
```